# Returning prompt value

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i'm working on a code that will return a prompt value of each case to a cell ("A1") but I can't seem to get it right, for example if I choose "case 1", I want the value on cell "A1" to be "1 - FCI18-0", is there a way to do this?. Here is my code below :

```
Sub TestFunction()
ans = InputBox("1 = FCI18-0" & vbCrLf & _
               "2 = FCI18-1" & vbCrLf & _
               "3 = FCI18-2" & vbCrLf & _
               "4 = FCI18-3", "Model")

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = InputBoxPrompt
End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub TestFunction()
  'Declare variables
  Dim test(3) As String
  Dim i as long
  'Set array with cases. Advantage of this set up is flexibility. In a later stage you can 
  'make a function that reads cases from a table in a (hidden) sheet into this array. 
  'This way you don't need to add new cases to your code, 
  'but you can add them in your excel sheet instead. 
  test(0) = "FCI18-0"
  test(1) = "FCI18-1"
  test(2) = "FCI18-2"
  test(3) = "FCI18-3"

  'read the input given by the user. You might want to add some checks here
  i = InputBox ("Which case?")

  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = test(i-1)
End Sub
```

Comment: `test(i)` should be `test(i-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select Case`

```
Sub TestFunction()
    ans = InputBox("1 = FCI18-0" & vbCrLf & _
                   "2 = FCI18-1" & vbCrLf & _
                   "3 = FCI18-2" & vbCrLf & _
                   "4 = FCI18-3", "Model")
    Select Case ans
        Case 1: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "1 = FCI18-0"
        Case 2: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "2 = FCI18-1"
        Case 3: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "3 = FCI18-2"
        Case 4: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "4 = FCI18-3"
    End Select
End Sub
```